# Preventing Cats.IO to be executed in parallel

Tags: multithreading, scala, cats-effect, fs2

Forcing Cats.IO to be evaluated on a dedicated thread pool

How can I prevent the line.split to be executed on the Blocker[IO] execution context?
I hoped the IO effect will be evaluated on Two dedicated threads obtained from  parEvalMapUnordered.
Should I shift context somehow?

```
    Blocker[IO].use { blocker => {
          val processorPipe: Pipe[IO, Byte, Byte] =
            src =>
              src.through(text.utf8Decode)
                .through(text.lines)
                .parEvalMapUnordered(2)(line => {
                  IO.eval(Eval.now {
                    println("Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getId)
                    line.split("\\W+")
                  })
                })
```

Output shows many threads:

```
Thread: 32
Thread: 32
...
Thread: 38
Thread: 38
...
Thread: 40
...
Thread: 41
```

Comment: I would guess you are then forcing the evaluation of the whole thing inside the `Blocker` EC

Comment: Do you want the `split` to happen on a specific thread pool or do you want it to not happen in parallel?

Not happening in parallel is very easy in this case; replace `parEvalMapUnordered` with `evalMap` - don't ask for parallelism if you don't want it.

It also doesn't make sense to really do that step in `IO` at all - it's not a side-effect, so it can just happen in a `map`